# how to pass special character '/' through a url

Tags: javascript, java, spring, urlencode

My url contains a special character '/'.Example :- localhost:8080/name=asdasd 11/2/2015. When I pass this through encodeURI to the spring framework , I need to differentiate '/' which is present in my variable and the one which is the actual separator. I have tried using './*' which returns me the string after the seperator but in case I have two args in my url which contain '/' then the above solution fails. How do I solve this ??

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for like this. Encode it only values.

```
 var myUrl ='localhost:8080/name=' + encodeURIComponent('asdasd 11/2/2015');
```

Comment: in the example u have given date  11/2/2015  contains '/'.. spring framework is not able to distinguish this '/' and '/'after localhost:8080 ....this is the problem I want to solve